# Make large number of webcalls

Tags: java, php

I have to make webcall to an external server at the rate of 5 tps. Every webcall usually takes around 7 secs to complete. How do I implement this. Would you recommend PHP for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Java solution since you tagged your question with Java. It'll make a request to a web site 5 times per second. Since you indicated that those requests can take a long time, it'll use up to 50 threads at once to avoid getting blocked.

```
final URL url = new URL("http://whitefang34.com");
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStream in = url.openStream();
            // process input
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // deal with exception
        }
    }
};

ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
long nextTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (true) {
    service.submit(runnable);
    long waitTime = nextTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
    Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, waitTime));
    nextTime += 200;
}
```

Comment: Will this execute the calls in parallel? They take longer than the time difference between them, from the question.

Comment: Yes it will execute up to 50 in parallel.

Comment: I think you meant `scheduleAtFixedRate`

Comment: Thanks Simon/WhiteFang, How can I pass a parameter to runnable in this case?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of one way to be able to access a variable inside of runnable. In this case however there's only one runnable and it's used for every call, so the URL can only be set once. What parameter do you want to pass exactly and are you expecting it to change over time?

Comment: i worked around somehow and now it seems to be working :). Can u please tell me how you got 200 and 50 in the above example. Thanks

Comment: You specified 5 transactions per second, so that's one request every 200 milliseconds. If they consistently took 7 seconds each then you'd need 35 parallel threads to handle running 5 per second. I only suggested 50 in case the calls sometimes took longer.

Comment: Updated the answer again so it truly runs at 5 per second.